# Return an Empty list rather than throwing null exception in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing a sql service to Get the list of items for a service.
The method looks like this,

```
public List<Items> GetList(string username)
        {
            string sql = "Select * From Items Where username = '{0}'";
            sql = string.Format(sql, Username);
            return base.Get(sql);
        }
```

Get method does all the code to get the data from the database and return to the list.
My question is when the username doesn't exist in the database it is throwing exception 'object reference not set to instance of an object'. Instead of throwing exception i want to return an empty List of items. The Item object consists of properties(ItemID, ItemName, ItemPlace)
or Give me any suggestions to implement it in a different way.

```
ItemID = null,
ItemName = null,
ItemPlace = null
```

Comment: 1) It's either `username` or `Username`. Pick one. 2) The code that's giving you trouble is in your base class, which you haven't provided, so no one can answer your question.

Comment: `return base.Get(sql) ?? new List<Items>();` would work just fine, provided you fix the other problem with `username` casing.

Comment: What if I enter `Blacksilver'; DROP TABLE Items; --` as my username?

Comment: There is definitely a potential for SQL injection, as Blacksilver points out, if username is being entered by a user.  If not, it's probably safe but not the best of practices.  I hope you have some sort of non-string ID to identify a user other than the username.  You should be using that instead.

Your problem is clearly in base.Get().  You could do what Ron suggests as a workaround, but should fix Get to work the way you want it to if you can.  If that's not a possibility because it's not your code, go with Ron's suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

take a look on the code, you have to modify your code accordingly.

```
Public List<Items> Get(string sql)
{

 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        var  ItemsList = new List<Items>();
        var Items = new Items()
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);       
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
               Items.ItemID  = dr["ItemID"].ToString();
               Items.ItemName = dr["ItemName"].ToString();                        
               Items.ItemPlace = dr["ItemPlace"].ToString();
               ItemsList.Add(Items);
        }

        if(ItemsList.Count == 0)
          {
             Items.ItemID = null;
             Items.ItemName = null;
             Items.ItemPlace = null;
             ItemsList.Add(Items);
          }

        return ItemsList;
    } 
}
```

Comment: _Instead of throwing exception i want to return an empty List of items_ In what world is that the answer to the question?